# What is this specific tool?

Tags: tools, hand-tools

Can anyone identify this? My best guess was some kind of tool for opening drain clean outs maybe?

The inside says “C.A. Inc.” and “D” which I am guessing is a size.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is an oil filter wrench.

For removing an oil filter from an engine.

It allows the mechanic to use a standard socket wrench to turn the filter.

Comment: Yes! I knew it looked familiar. I changed my own oil maybe 3 times about 20 years ago before deciding it was too big of a pain for me.